# Why I am getting "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed" when i execute my query?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
String sql = "Select * from EmployeeAccount";

try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");    
   Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AttendanceSystemTest","root","");   
   Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

   String user=txtid.getText();

   String pwd=new String (password.getPassword());
   int loop=0;

   while(rs.next()) {
      String uname=rs.getString("Emp_ID");
      String password=rs.getString("Password");

      if ((user.equals(uname)) && (pwd.equals(password))) {
         String s1 = "insert into Attendance (Emp_ID,Date,Time_in) Values ('" + user + "', now(), curtime());";
         stmt.executeUpdate(s1);
         loop++;
      }
  }

  rs.close();

  if (loop==0) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password not in database!");
   }
}

catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

Comment: Format your code! At the moment your question is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `stmt.executeUpdate(s1);` inside the `while(rs.next())` loop closes the `ResultSet`, and therefore, the next call to `rs.next()` throws the exception.

You should use a different `Statement` instance to execute that update.

> **A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is** closed, **re-executed**, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

([Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html))

Comment: Your answer would be much improved if you took a moment to explain *why* the `ResultSet` should be closed before re-using the same `Statement` object to do something else.

Comment: @GordThompson Actually, my original answer was wrong. After the code was formatted, it was easier to see the real problem.